# Pass input from a React.js/Electron app to a Python script?

Tags: python, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to build a cross platform user interface in React.JS/Electron for [this user's project automation Python script](https://github.com/jarodburchill/ProjectAutomation). My issue is that the Python script needs the user to input the project's directory, Github credentials, etc., and I have no idea how to pass the data from an input field in my React/Electron application to the Python script. My question is: is it posible to pass input between the two?

Comment: Looks like you just have to write a config file, not directly pass values between code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about React very much but you can check if it has capabilities of running command inside operating system (I can bet it can).

If not then you can try modify this (python) project code by adding simple endpoint to pass your variables and run function in python. Websockets will do the job. Flask/Django will be huge overkill but will also work. You have probably guessed already that the React's job will be to call this endpoint with http request.